# Will the Samsung Series 9 models boot from USB?

Tags: laptop, usb, bios

I'm thinking about getting either one of these Series 9 Models:

1. NP900X3C-A01US - Win 7
2. NP900X3C-A05US - Win 8

I'd want to do a complete wipe on either one, but what to make certain that the unit is able to boot from USB. The new Zenbook Prime does not have that option listed in the BIOS.

Can anybody verify that they are able to accomplish this?

Comment: All modern laptops can boot from USB.

Comment: @Moab yes, even those laptops,  but samsung laptops stump samsung technical support on how to boot form USB.  I recall calling them 2013ish, they didn't know, then I finally found out, I called them back and told them. Called them back again, spoke to another that didn't know, and told him. The entire team was and probably still is, stumped on how to boot from USB!

Answer (score 4):

If it's the same BIOS as the Samsung Series 3, then yes but it's tricky to find the option in the BIOS.

Google picked up this link when I was looking.. a blog mentioning the aptio bios and that kind of laptop!  [The blogger's post](http://blog.radwell.codes/2012/08/aptio-bios-usb-boot/) helped somewhat but 2 comments in particular helped more.  The blogger's post mentions some stuff and a  comment mentions about a part of the BIOS that says BBS priorities

And in case that doesn't quite cut it, another poster(me), had some luck, solved it and commented with a solution regarding his Series 3, which takes what the blogger wrote + a comment about BBS priorities, and solved it and explained-

And this is essentially the answer.

> On 2012-12-10 at 18:46 in comment there, I wrote:
>   Aptio bios has hardly any options and
>   doesn’t show much. A very poor BIOS generally.
>
> I have a samsung NP350
>
> I couldn’t see any option to boot from USB. I updated the BIOS. still
>   nope. I disabled fast BIOS saved restarted, but no new USB option
>   appears under “boot override” or anywhere – it seemed.
>
> A normal/decent BIOS e.g. even on a cheap Dell, besides showing far
>   more in the BIOS, often has an option where a function key offers a
>   boot menu.
>
> But I tried all the function keys and the only one is F2 to go into
>   the BIOS.
>
> In the end, I saw that Indeed one had to set advanced.. fast bios
>   mode..to disabled, and restart. But then my USB stick was under
>   Boot….Boot device priority….. then it said CD/DVD drive BBS priorities
>   Hard drive BBS priorities Choose Hard drive priorities Then I saw my
>   USB key listed.
>
> So, it was within 3 layers!

That which is quoted directly above, has solved it for many people, perhaps for anybody. Hopefully samsung tech support will take note 'cos it had stumped them.

So the comment points out that it's through 3 layers with titles including the term "BBS priorities". the original poster said that the option is called "boot override".

BTW Another user says this of the series 5 aptio bios.

> secure boot method option where I could switch from UEFI to CMS
>   (whatever this CMS means). That did the trick on my NP550P5C and the
>   USB boot option came alive.

Comment: Finally! :-) Thank you! Disabled `Fast BIOS Mode`

Comment: @IonicăBizău  some (perhaps you too), and perhaps all,  have found the 3 layers point helped them,  and BBS priorities, not just disabling the fast bios mode..

Answer (score 3):

The option often does not appear unless there is a USB device connected.  Most (likely all) will boot from USB these days.

Answer (score 2):

In Samsung series 9 you need in bois setup (which you reach by pressing F2 when the computer boots),

to choose boot Tab, and disable the "Secure Mode" and in OS mode selection to choose "UEFI AND CSM OS" to make it work.

It still asked me next, to but with F10 and choose my USB Drive.

To me it worked on usb 3 & 2.
Good luck

Comment: @NVZ well you didn't try everything. The "secure mode" thing was mentioned in my last paragraph. By the way, is yours a series 3 or 5 or 9?

Comment: @barlop Series 5. And I think I was excited too soon. It didn't work. I might be writing up a new question some time this week.

Comment: @NVZ  if you plug a usb device in, and then try what I wrote in my answer, for how to get to the bios/acpi, does it really not work?  And does it work on another computer(so it's definitely a bootable usb). Do you even have the options that my answer mentions?

Comment: @barlop I will write in detail what I did and what results I found. But now I'm a bit tied up. Will ping you if/when I post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can  boot from USB.

Almost all (if not all) modern laptops can  boot from USB. Most do so without a problem. Some require the USB device to be present before they boot, or even for it to be enabled in the BIOS.  (Read: Insert USB device, boot, go to BIOS, mark USB as bootable, reboot (from USB)).

The NP900X3C-A01US comes with two USB ports. One USB2, one USB3.
[You can  only use the USB2 port to boot](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1737086.html).