# Samsung NP550P5C boot priority issue

Tags: bios

I have a new Samsung 5 series with Windows 8 and I can't make it boot from DVD/USB.I entered BIOS and disabled fast bios mode but when i enter boot priorities the only option i have is Windows boot manager. When I try to enter Windows boot manager, it always restarts.Could anyone please tell me how can I make it boot from DVD?

Comment: What happens if, during boot, you press F8 lots - does it take you to the boot menu where you can select it? Also, what DVD are you trying to boot from?

Comment: Does my answer here help?   http://superuser.com/questions/508271/will-the-samsung-series-9-models-boot-from-usb and for anybody having an issue getting into the BIOS on that or similar laptop,  0:39 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peEJwjJ_Uf8

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following two changes:

- First, you have to turn off *Fast startup* option in *Power Options* menu <sup>[1]</sup>.
- Then you have to enter BIOS <sup>[2]</sup> and disable *Fast Bios Mode*. I have also changed an option so I can boot not only UEFI operating systems (but I am not sure if it is required).

If you do this, and then save the settings,
you can change boot priority (<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> while loading the BIOS).

References:

[1] [EightForums](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)
[2] [7Tutorials](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-boot-uefi-bios-any-windows-81-tablet-or-device)
[3] [Notebook Review Forums](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/samsung-series-5-np550p5c-thread.687007/page-5#post-894362)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 installation on the Samsung NP550P5C.
Disable the SAFE BOOT option in the bios first.

After that you will need to convert the drive to a GPT partition using Diskpart on the Windows 7 CD.
Use shift+F10 after CD boot.﻿