# Samsung Laptop cannot read my bootable disc

Tags: laptop, bios, bootable-media

I have a Samsung Series 5 laptop (NP530U4C). I want to format it and install Ubuntu 12 LTS.
I can access the BIOS and set the hard disk priority but it does not detect my bootable disc on startup. How can I make it read my boot disc? Please help. I already tried CD and Flash Disk, no luck.

http://www.samsung.com/ph/consumer/monitor-peripherals-printer/notebook-pc/ultra-portable/NP530U4C-S03PH

Comment: What type of partition do you have currently GPT or MBR?

Comment: @Ramhound do you really think it makes a difference whether he has GPT or MBR, considering he is asking about a "bootable disc" disc tends to mean optical. So, he's not talking about a bootable hard disk. He mentioned CD and Flash disk.

Comment: does this help http://techunlogic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/samsung-series-7-chronos-how-to-boot.html  Try disabling fast bios mode, that might at least help for usb. also here http://superuser.com/questions/508271/will-the-samsung-series-9-models-boot-from-usb

Comment: When I switch it on I only see the Samsung logo then it is stacked there. But I can reach my BIOS via by pressing F2. I can't make it boot. I hear a beep code, maybe that's POST. So maybe my hardware is ok.

Comment: @tungsten_carbide I edited my comment to add a superuser link to an answer I gave once, note my answer at that superuser link that I mention in that comment and try that too