# How do I change the boot order on a Acer Aspire 7551-2531?

Tags: boot, bootable-media, acer-aspire

I'm trying to boot into a USB on my computer, but I cannot find a way to change the boot order to make USBs the top boot priority. Any help would be great.

Comment: -1 Normally if somebody says they can't change the boot order, it suggests they're in the BIOS. It's like somebody saying they can't tie their shoelaces up, it implies they have shoelaces (as who would be so stupid as to talk as if they have a problem tying their shoelaces when the reason is because they don't have any shoelaces or shoes). Turns out you suggest now in comment to Lord's answer, that you haven't even got  into the BIOS so no surprise you couldn't change the boot order.

Comment: @barlop You're assuming that everybody knows you do that in the BIOS. The question made it pretty clear that is not the case.

Comment: @Tetsujin The question does not even come close to making it clear or even suggesting that he doesn't know that he needs to be in the BIOS / that he doesn't understand his own question / that he doesn't know what he is asking. Quote what part of the question makes that clear

Comment: @barlop "cannot find a way to change" Once you're in the BIOS even with no knowledge, it's just a case of poking at the buttons til you see it. I guess I'm just used to extrapolating from user questions - years of helpline ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe you need some more years, as the following example stumped samsung tech support, but eventually I found the answer and posted it here, and called samsung back to let them know. Check my answer to this question. Sometimes options can be quite hidden.Also i've seen cases where slightly technical users (ones that easily know what a BIOS is) are poking around and can't find how to do something. This samsung one was the trickiest one and stumped many people even online http://superuser.com/questions/508271/will-the-samsung-series-9-models-boot-from-usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried pressing F2 on startup? Press the power button, then repeatedly press F2 until you reach BIOS. It feels a little silly ;)

[This Acer help page](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7550/~/changing-boot-order) has more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you had to mash it. When i tried I just pressed it once and it took me to a completely different screen.

Comment: Normally if somebody says  they can't change the boot order, it suggests they're in the BIOS. It's like somebody saying they can't tie their shoelaces up, it implies they have shoelaces (as who would be so stupid as to talk as if they have a problem tying their shoelaces when the reason is because they don't have any shoelaces or shoes).   This guy says he can't change the boot order, and it turned out he couldn't even get into the BIOS. You assumed he was asking a daft question and he was. Under normal circumstances. You are "lucky" that you were right, and he is lucky too.

Comment: @Starvr344, if this has solved your issue, please mark it as an answer. I need the reputation!

Comment: @DavidLord if you want more rep and you don't have that many answers then bear in mind that one way to earn rep is to ask good questions

Comment: @barlop Thanks for the advice. I have the problem - and suspect many here do - that most questions I have can be answered by hard thought and putting some time into Google, and under those circumstances it's rare to come up with a good question. Will certainly post a question if something comes up.

Comment: @DavidLord if you have a problem and it isn't immediately on google, you can post it and answer it yourself if you solve it. check my profile I asked about 100 questions. Sometimes I post the Q and A after solving it. That is still helpful for the database. It is a good question if it saves others a lot of hard work, so they find the answer much quicker thanks to your research.