# Boot priority list empty

Tags: hard-drive, boot, uefi, boot-manager

I have just bought a second hand Samsung Series 5 Ultratouch NP540U3C-A02UK. It has Phoenix SecureCore Tiano BIOS, version P07ABH. I bought it without a hard drive and when it arrived I installed the SSD from my previous laptop and booted the new one.

It would not boot and entered a boot loop a number of time before giving the error "All boot options are tried...." When pressing F2, The boot tab is empty and on the other tab pressing enter on windows boot manager does nothing. Entering the BIOS setup, SATA port 1 shows my hard drive but when I enter the boot tab and select "Boot Device Priority" the list is totally empty:

[image: screenshot]

The BIOS says that the cert key is for windows 8 and I have tried putting a hard drive with windows 8 in it but that was also not recognized. I have also tried blank HDD and bootable USB drives. Fast boot and secure boot are disabled and the UEFI is enabled. have tried legacy mode, resetting BIOS to default and resetting the whole BIOS.

If anyone can help that would be much appreciated. If you need any more information just ask.

Comment: try and use this for ideas on options to look at, it may help  http://superuser.com/questions/508271/will-the-samsung-series-9-models-boot-from-usb

Comment: That thread only gives solutions that involve settings in the BIOS, I have already disabled fast boot and secure boot as stated in my question but thanks for trying.

Comment: You write "That thread only gives solutions that involve settings in the BIOS, "   <--- Your entire post is about settings in the BIOS.  Your post is clear but even so, I suggest it might help further if you take a picture with your phone and post it.

Comment: I apoligise for the tone of my previosius commment, I was pretty stressed with a number of laptop repairs :) Yes I can upload a picture, I had one in a prevoius thred but the link stopped working and someone said it wasnt verry useful anyway. The reason I cover all of the settings in my question is to save time and give people as much detail as possible so they don't have to go throught things that have already been done.

Comment: Maybe you bought a faulty laptop and the problem maybe physical not just the bios configuration. Can you explain this: "The BIOS says that the cert key is for windows 8 "

Comment: Are you sure your laptop has the BIOS firmware and not UEFI firmware?

Comment: In response to emirjonb, I don't dull fully understand the cert key  but as far as I kniw  it is that the laptop originally had windows 8, the product key for the OS is stored in the BIOS. However it should still be possible to put any other OS on there.  As for Hennes' comment what is the difference and how would I be able to tell?