# Samsung Notebook USB Boot issue

Tags: grub, usb-boot

I've search everywhere for how to get my Samsung Notebook(Model is: NP355V5C-A01US) to boot from a USB Device. The only thing I have found was to disable the FastBoot option, which I have done. It DOES show up in the boot menu, but whgen I select the USB drive to boot from, it goes to the GRUB boot menu to choose which OS I want to boot since my HDD is paritioned. I don't see the USB boot menu. I have tested this on other computers and it does work, just not on this PC.

Comment: does my answer here help http://superuser.com/questions/508271/will-the-samsung-series-9-models-boot-from-usb  Also, perhaps there's an issue with your USB contents or weird compatibility issue between stick and comp. Have you tried that stick in another comp and another stick with different bootable contents in that comp?

Comment: I see you say you've tested the usb stick in other comps. Have you tried other bootable usb sticks with other contents, in your samsung notebook?

Comment: You say "It DOES show up in the boot menu" and you say "I don't see the USB boot menu"  Can you be specific about what boot menu you are talking about.  What function key gets there. And since you see a boot menu and it offers USB, what do you mean by "usb boot menu"? And is your BIOS/UEFI seeing anything particular about the USB stick e.g. that it's  a sandisk cruzer or whatever

Comment: That DID help. It was under the 3 section layer part. Thank  you so much. I wish i would have found that when searching.

Comment: Unplug your hard drives.  And when you say "I select the USB drive to boot from, it goes to the GRUB boot menu to choose "  <-- Are you trying to say that it is booting from your hard disk - anyhow, unplug your hard disk. Also provide references in your question to where you found what it is that you tried

Comment: Can you include the places where you searched? It'd actually help people if you posted the answer in those places where you found the answers insufficient.  When I found the answer (the very hard way), I posted it in at least two places, to add to the posts that were already there that hadn't mentioned that answer.

Comment: I searched using GOogle, DuckDuckGO, Youtube, and here.
On here I probably should have been more specific, I searched for Samsung Notbook USB Boot

Comment: I mean you should include the links

Comment: And is it really called "fastboot" on your one?  According to the answer I wrote it's  called FastBIOS Mode

Comment: The link I used was the one you provided me with, but I don't remember if it was FastBoot or FastBIOS, I'll have to check in a bit